# How to print iterate letter in perl

Tags: perl

I need some hindsight on how to print to get the expected outcome.How can I make automatically iterate for the letter for just the data I have, like `i++`, and how can I reset the value of `i` for each `HOME`?

Expected Outcome:

```
RESIDENCE LIST
a) HOME 1   1. Albert Einstein
            2. Adriana
            3. Anna
   LOCATION USA
b) HOME 2   1. Blaine Pascal
            2. Caroline Herschel
            3. Cecilia Payne-Gaposchkin
   LOCATION GERMANY
c) HOME 3   1. Dorothy Hodgkin
            2. Edmond Halley
            3. Edwin Powell Hubble
   LOCATION INDIA 

use strict;
use warnings;

my i=1;
my @alphabets=("a".."z");
my @homes=qw(
HOME1
HOME2
HOME3
);
my @residences=qw(
HOME1 Albert Einstein
HOME1 Adriana
HOME1 Anna
HOME2 Blaine Pascal
HOME2 Caroline Herschel
HOME2 Cecilia Payne-Gaposchkin
HOME3 Dorothy Hodgkin
HOME3 Edmond Halley
HOME3 Edwin Powell Hubble
);
my @location=qw(
USA
GERMANY
INDIA
);

print  "RESIDENCE LIST \n\n";

foreach my $alphabet(@alphabets)
{
    print "$alphabet)";

    foreach my  $home(@homes) 
    {
        foreach my $location(@location)
        {
            foreach my $residence (@residences)
            {
            if ($home=~ /^residence(.*)/)
            {
            print "\thome\t";
            print $i++,")$1\n";     
            }
            }
        print "\t $location\n"; 
    }

}
```

New Script

```
foreach my  $home(@homes) 
{
   my $i=1;
   foreach my $location(@location)
   {
   foreach my $residence (@residences)
   {
       if ($home=~ /^residence(.*)/)
       {
       print $alphabet++."\n";
       print "\thome\t";
       print $i++,")$1\n";      
       }
       else
       {
       next:
       }
    }

    print "\t $location\n";
    } 
}
```

Outcome that I get

```
    a) HOME 1   1. Albert Einstein
    b) HOME 1   2. Adriana
    c) HOME 1   3. Anna
    d) LOCATION USA
    e) HOME 2   1. Blaine Pascal
    f) HOME 2   2. Caroline Herschel
    g) HOME 2   3. Cecilia Payne-Gaposchkin
    h) LOCATION GERMANY
    i) HOME 3   1. Dorothy Hodgkin
    j) HOME 3   2. Edmond Halley
    k) HOME 3   3. Edwin Powell Hubble
    l) LOCATION INDIA
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `$alphabet`, initialize it like you do with `$i`, but with `a`. Perls `++` operator knows how to work on letters:

```
my $alphabet = 'a';

...
    $alphabet++;
```

Instead of having `$i` as factually global variable, declare it one loop level above where you want it to be reset:

```
...
foreach my $home (@homes) {
    my $i = 1;
    foreach my $location (@location) {
    ...
        $i++
    ....
    };
}
```

#### See also

[perlop on Auto-increment](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

Comment: Maybe you can tell us where exactly you are having problems? This is not a code writing service and we expect people to do their homework themselves.

Comment: I can't print out like the expected outcome.

Comment: You will need to show us the outcome you get and the outcome you want, and the code you use if you want advice what to change.

Comment: The output you show cannot come from the code you show. You never output/increment the letter in front. Maybe your problem is that you always print all stuff, but want to print empty space in some of the cases?

Comment: yes. Look at my expected outcome and the outcome that I get. I already update the missing $alphabet++.